# Organic Groups user sectioning

Tags: organic-groups, users

I have just set up a site working with Organic Groups. I am now adding users and user permissions.

I create a type called **group** which serves as the group node and **page** that serves as the group node content.

**The issue is I want my authenticated users to add new page content but only within groups I have assigned them to.**

Can anyone advice how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

when your users post new "page" content they can select the associated group. You could make that a required field.

Comment: thanks but I don't want to give users the option to post into groups they don't belong to

Comment: when you edit the "group audience" field for your "page" node you can set a value for "input type". If you select Automatically decide the input according to user permissions (Recommended)" then users can only "select from the groups they belong to".

Comment: This answer is correct -- the only groups that show up in the selection field is for groups users belong to.